# prevent scrolling on horizontal collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, collectionview

I have a horizontal collection view that display only 2 images and each image takes up half the screen. I want to prevent scrolling by making images look like they are fixed and no move.

```
// sizeForItemAt
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if collectionView == self.topCollectionView {
        let height = view.frame.size.height
        let width = view.frame.size.width
    
        return CGSize(width: width * (1/2), height: height * (1/2))
    }
    return CGSize()

}

// minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if collectionView == self.topCollectionView {
       return 3
    }
    return 3

}

// insetForSectionAt
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    if collectionView == self.topCollectionView {
        let sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 4, bottom: 3, right: 4)
        return sectionInset
    }

    let sectionInset2 = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 4, bottom: 3, right: 4)
    return sectionInset2

}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be scrollable by default. Seems  like you are setting invalid size that is wider than the collection's width.

Comment: i added my code above

Comment: (Deleted my previous comment. Didn't grasp something.) Okay. What is your reason for using a `UICollectionView` for two horizontal images that take half the width? I went down this route over a year ago. Let's think this through. A collection view versus a horizontal `UIStackView`. I can't think of any reason that wouldn't work - except for **why** such a thing exists. Apple trying to make it easy for auto layout constraints. So let's try something simpler... a scroll view. (After all that's all any collection view really is.) Second comment in a moment....

Comment: So what is a scroll view? The base for everything from a UITableView through a UICollectionView. In my case, I wanted thumbnails along the bottom. UICollcetionView was *way* too much. Even a UIStackView! But since I needed more thumbnails than the screen allows, I chose a UIScrollview. But your need? I'm not sure, but all you've said is **two** views that need to **each** take up half the width. That can - and IMHO should - be done without any "container view" and simply through auto layout constraints these two views directly.

Comment: you are right i will try something simpler

Comment: i am trying  to disable scrolling from attributes inspector  and  it is working now